# Read lines of text file into array, using double pointer and malloc

Tags: c

I want to read lines of a text file, and the content of it is as below.

first
second
third

I've already written some code, but the result was different from what I expected. I hope you can help me a little. (code below)

```c
/*
content of test.txt

first
second
third
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  // double pointer for two string lines
  // and the two string lines will be pointed by (char *) pointer
  FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  char **lst = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));  // corrected 2 -> 3

  // read lines until feof(fp) is not Null
  // Only 2 lines will be read by this loop
  int i = 0;
  while (!feof(fp)) {
    char line[10];
    fgets(line, 10, fp);
    *(lst + i) = line;
    printf("%d : %s", i, *(lst + i));
    i++;
  }

  /*
  Result:

  0 : first
  1 : second
  2 : third     // Why was this line printed here?

  There are 3 lines, not 2 lines!
  */

  printf("\n\n");

  int j;
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%d : %s\n", j, *(lst + j));
  }

  /*
  result:

  0 : third
  1 : third
  2 : third

  The whole lines were not printed correctly!
  */

  free(lst);
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

0 : first
1 : second
2 : third

Many thanks.

Comment: What was the actual output?

Comment: Do you use an IDE? Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, learn; set some breakpoints, step through your code, line by line, examinking variables & you will soon find your problem (and not need us :-)

Comment: See [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1968)

Comment: Hint: instead of `*(lst + i)` write `lst[i]`. It's exactly the same thing, but latter is the more common way to do it.

Comment: Surprisingly similar to [C read entire line of file {closed}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775052/c-read-entire-line-of-file). You would also benefit from [How to read correctly certain strings from file in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964255/how-to-read-correctly-certain-strings-from-file-in-c/54967788?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#54967788)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you are allocating space for an array of *two* `char*`s and you have a *single* statically sized buffer for a string. But you’re attempting to read *three* strings. Where do you think the space for the strings is coming from? You’re not allocating it.

You need to make your various numbers match up: allocate an array of *three* strings, and then allocate *three* string buffers:

```
char **lst = malloc(3 * sizeof *lst);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lst[i] = malloc(10);
    fgets(lst[i], 10, fp);
}
```

And don’t forget to `free` all allocated buffers subsequently:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    free(lst[i]);
}
free(lst);
```

… of course this code isn’t terribly great either since it hard-codes the number of lines you can read, and the maximum line length. But it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I corrected my code, but output is still incorrect.

Comment: @Larynx You only corrected one of several errors I mentioned.